# Can Inkscape losslessly save PDFs?

Tags: pdf, inkscape

I need to remove pages from a PDF document and the saved file must be lossless due to barcodes and QR codes. I have finished editing in Inkscape, but will the final pages be lossless?

import PDF settings:

[image: import PDF settings]

save as PDF settings:

[image: save as PDF settings]

Comment: Have you tried saving and checked the files?

Comment: @music2myear: I don't know how to verify the integrity of two PDF pages. On a cursory glance the imported page is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF you imported used vector graphics for items like the QR code, then yes, the PDF you *export* will also have vector graphics.  Through some experimentation, it seems that Inkscape doesn't produce exactly the same raster (bitmap) graphics when exporting to PDF, but it should be good enough for items like a QR code.

If the goal is only to remove pages, have you considered other options like Acrobat (for Windows or Mac) or pdftk (for Linux)?

Comment: I picked Inkscape since the program seems to be the most widely-used free PDF editor. I will look at other programs if they have advantages in exporting.

Comment: Yes, I guess it depends on what someone has to edit.  If it's changing the actual graphics and text of a page, Inkscape is pretty good (although I've only ever used Inkscape for illustrations and diagrams).  If you're stitching PDFs together or removing whole pages, other programs are better than Inkscape.  Good luck.